# When Is The Object Eligible For Garbage Collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In the code below, given that `amethod` has been called. At what point/line is the Object originally referenced by `myObject`, eligible for Garbage Collection?

```
class Test {
  private Object classObject;

  public void amethod() {
    Object myObject = new Object();
    classObject = myObject;
    myObject = null;
  }
}
```

And if `classObject` or `amethod` had an access modifier of public, protected, default or static, would it affect what point the Object is eligible for Garbage Collection? If so, how would it be affected?

- My first thought is that the Object is eligible for Garbage Collection when the Test object is eligible for Garbage Collection.
- But then again. The optimizer may know that the classObject is never read from in which case `classObject = myObject;` would be optimized out and `myObject = null;` is the point it is eligible for Garbage Collection.

Comment: When you say "the Object", do you refer `Test` class instance, `Object classObject` or `Object myObject`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza "the Object" always refers to the Object originally referenced by myObject.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The object will not become a candidate for garbage collection until **all** references to it are discarded. Java objects are assigned by reference so when you had

```
   classObject = myObject;
```

You assigned another reference to the same object on the heap. So this line

```
   myObject = null;
```

Only gets rid of one reference. To make `myObject` a candidate for garbage collection, you have to have

```
  classObject = null;
```

Comment: Are compilers not allow to optimise away the assignment to the ivar as described in the question?

Comment: Based on a variety of factors including the type of reference (weak vs soft), it's not straightforward (or safe) to depend on this optimization at any rate @KartickVaddadi

Comment: @VaddadiKartick: the specification states *exactly* that this kind of optimization is not allowed for a heap variable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47311943/2711488)…

Comment: The theory mentioned in this answer implicitly assumes that all references are strong references. The answer does not take into account other types of references such as Soft and Weak references. However as far as the provided example is concerned, the answer is not wrong.

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. An object is eligible for garbage collection when there's no longer a reference path from a GC root to the object. The difference here means that if you create a circular reference chain, it will still get garbage collected once it's no longer reachable. Despite there always being a reference to the each object in the chain.

Answer (score 6):

From Book **OCA Java SE 7**

> An object is marked as **eligible** to be garbage collected when it
>   can no longer be accessed, which can happen when the object goes out
>   of scope. It can also happen when an object’s reference variable is
>   assigned an explicit null value or is reinitialized.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually addressed precisely by the Java Language Specification, [§12.6.1,  Implementing Finalization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1) :

> Optimizing transformations of a program can be designed that reduce the number of objects that are reachable to be less than those which would naively be considered reachable. For example, a Java compiler or code generator may choose to set a variable or parameter that will no longer be used to `null` to cause the storage for such an object to be potentially reclaimable sooner.
>
> Another example of this occurs if the values in an object's fields are stored in registers. The program may then access the registers instead of the object, and never access the object again. This would imply that the object is garbage. …

**But**

> … Note that this sort of optimization is only allowed if references are on the stack, not stored in the heap.
>
> > For example, consider the Finalizer Guardian pattern:
> >
> > ```
> >    class Foo {
> >        private final Object finalizerGuardian = new Object() {
> >            protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
> >                /* finalize outer Foo object */
> >            }
> >        }
> >    }
> > ```
> >
> > The finalizer guardian forces `super.finalize` to be called if a subclass overrides `finalize` and does not explicitly call `super.finalize`.
> >
> > If these optimizations are allowed for references that are stored on the heap, then a Java compiler can detect that the `finalizerGuardian` field is never read, null it out, collect the object immediately, and call the finalizer early. This runs counter to the intent: the programmer probably wanted to call the `Foo` finalizer when the `Foo` instance became unreachable. This sort of transformation is therefore not legal: the inner class object should be reachable for as long as the outer class object is reachable.

This example can be applied 1:1 to your example, as long as the object is referenced by the instance field `classObject`, it can not get garbage collected earlier than the `Test` instance containing the reference.

Note, however, that the aggressive optimizations mentioned in the specification are still allowed, when being applied to the code using the `Test` instance. The earlier-than-expected collection may happen, as long as *both*, the `Test` instance and the referenced object are collected together. In this case, the following aspect specified in [§12.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6) applies:

> The Java programming language imposes no ordering on finalize method calls. Finalizers may be called in any order, or even concurrently.

So it’s perfectly possible that the `Test` instance is collected earlier than the object referenced by `classObject` whereas the “inner” object’s finalizer is invoked earlier. The only thing that is guaranteed, is, that when the inner object’s finalizer runs, the outer object is unreachable (or has a pending or concurrent finalization). Since in your example, neither has a non-trivial finalizer, that doesn’t matter anyway…

Answer (score 3):

Your idea that the private object may be GC'd right away because no other code is able to access it does have some traction, but this would mess with the general semantics of Java memory management. For example, if that object implemented `finalize`, and Java semantics clearly dictates when an object is eligible for garbage collection, that finalizer method would be have to be called against the specification.

Also note that the object in turn may reference other objects, with even more complicated possible outcomes. Not to mention the object is reachable by Reflection anytime and it would make no sense for the field to be observed to suddenly change to `null` even if no code could have made that assignment.

To conclude, there are many reasons why your idea of optimization would not work in the wider picture.

Comment: The strongest reason being that [it has been ruled out explicitly by the specification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47311943/2711488)…

Answer (score 0):

Since you are holding `myObject` in `classObject`(**reference is maintained**), it(object in memory referenced through classObject) will not be available for Garbage collection until instance of `Test` is freed up/unloaded.

Comment: after executing `amethod` method, `myObject` will become available for GC but `classObject` won't.

Answer (score 0):

No object is eligible for garbage collection here  because you are creating two reference for the same object and you are giving null to only one reference but other reference is still pointing your object

Answer (score 0):

> In the code below, given that amethod has been called. At what point/line is the Object originally referenced by myObject, eligible for Garbage Collection?

Your question is nonsensical because there is a disconnect between your high-level source code and the low-level representation (global roots in registers, on the stack and in global variables) that the garbage collector sees.

Your phrase "eligible for garbage collection" presumably means at what point does a heap-allocated block of memory become unreachable. So your question can only be answered by making a lot of (dubious) assumptions about what heap allocates and how long the generated code will keep references.